# Чем принципиально отличается национальный стереотип от этнического?

Tags: терминология

и можно ли как-то обосновать неразличение этнического и национального стереотипа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала надо определить, чем этнос отличается от нации? ЭТНОС -  это исторически возникшая устойчивая социальная группировка людей, объединенных  общим языком, территориально, исторически. Этнос может быть представлен   племенем, народностью, нацией.  НАЦИЯ - это  общность людей, которая дополнительно  приобретает общую политическую и экономическую жизнь и культуру. Нация становится тогда нацией, когда этнос превращается в субъект мировой истории. Соответственно, понятие стереотипа можно применить как к этносу, так и к нации.

О СТЕРЕОТИПАХ http://brunner.kgu.edu.ua/index.php/referats/78-psy-anthropology/1511-2014-03-01-22-42-38

Социальный стереотип возникает на основе восприятия, не связанного с прямым опытом: мы представляем себе многие вещи до того, как мы их познаем на опыте. Этнические стереотипы — это один из видов социальных стереотипов, которые описывают членов этнических групп, приписываются им или ассоциируются с ними. Этнический стереотип подразделяется на два вида: автостереотипы и гетеростереотипы. Автостереотипы — это мнения, суждения, оценки, относимые к данной этнической общности ее представителями.Обычно автостереотипы содержат комплекс положительных оценок. Гетеростереотипы — совокупность оценочных суждений, выносимых о других народах представителями данной этнической общности.

СТЕРЕОТИПЫ НАЦИОНАЛЬНЫХ ХАРАКТЕРОВ http://www.vaal.ru/show.php?id=91
В список исследуемых стереотипов вошли американцы, англичане, евреи, немцы, русские, украинцы, французы и японцы.

Answer (score 2):

А это из какой вообще дисциплины?
Если из какой-нибудь социопсихологии или исторической этнологии (они несколько по-разному трактуют понятия), то на вопрос, хоть он имеет некоторое отношение к лингвистике, ответить без профильных специалистов невозможно, это их компетенция.
А если это проблема из области чистой лингвистики (или социолигвистики), то я не помню, чтобы она использовала понятие "национальный стереотип".

Ну конечно, еще можно что-то из общих соображений сказать. 
Понятие этноса шире понятия национальности (или нации), поэтому в каких-то случаях "национальный стреотип", видимо, просто неприменимо. Это так, например, для малых субэтносов,  отдельными нациями не являющихся - племен, изолированных групп, социально обособленных групп (казачество, скажем). "Этнический стереотип" для них - это понятный термин, применимый. А "национальный"? Сомнительно. Так что с таких позиций, это все-таки несколько разные вещи.